# How do I change payment gateway name at checkout in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, payment-gateway, checkout

I use paymentsense and paypal as my payment gateway. The payment options comes as ‘PaymentSense’ or ‘PayPal’. As customers might not understand what ‘PaymentSense’ is, I want to change it to ‘Card Payment’ instead since customers are more familiar with that.

My question now is how can I change the ‘PaymentSense’ to ‘Card Payment’ in checkout? I can post image because I don't have up to 10 reputation.

Many thanks,
Joe.

Comment: In your module class code search for PaymentSense text and replace.Probably a Const value will have PaymentSense you need to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most innocuous method of changing labels in Magento is to first check the .csv translation files in the directory "/app/locale/en_US" (replace en_US with whichever language used if you're using multi-lang websites).

Each .csv contains a slew of labels in that particular area (paypal.csv for example). Look to see if the extension author was thorough enough to add a "paymentsense.csv" or something like it to the folder. I recommend opting for opening these files in a text editor rather than Excel and using the "Find..." feature to find the label you're looking for.

Each .csv file follows the same layout, for example:

```
"PayPal Merchant Pages Style","PayPal Merchant Pages Style"
"PayPal Payment Gateways","PayPal Payment Gateways"
"PayPal Payment Solutions","PayPal Payment Solutions"
"PayPal Pro","PayPal Pro"
```

Each line is one label, the first is the default, the second is what you want it to say. If I were to change the "Paypal Pro" label to say "PayPal Professional", I would change it to:

```
"PayPal Pro","PayPal Professional"
```

Magento would gladly replace the label for me. You may need to refresh your cache to get the changes to take.

If the developer did not add this into the extension, ultimately you'll have to scour through the code (either template files or underlying code structure) to make the change directly. Remember, when editing files in the app/code or app/design directories, make sure to copy them to the same structure under app/code/local or app/design/frontend/your_design/your_theme/template folders.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to change the title in the magento backend.

Comment: -=facepalm=- Sometimes, the most obvious answer escapes me. Glad you got it fixed!